# Array does not contain a definition for 'AsReadOnly'

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am using C# with .NET Core 1.1 under OS X (target framework is `netstandard1.6`) and I am getting an odd error for a missing method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] array = { 1, 2, 3 };
        ReadOnlyCollection<int> result = Array.AsReadOnly(array);
    }
}
```

Compilation of the program shown above results in the error

```
error CS0117: 'Array' does not contain a definition for 'AsReadOnly'
```

Is `AsReadOnly` not available in .NET Core or am I missing something else?

Comment: Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.asreadonly--1?view=netstandard-1.6#System_Array_AsReadOnly__1___0___ , it looks like it's not supported.

Comment: But you can always do `new ReadOnlyCollection(array)`

Comment: The implementation is merely `return new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(array);` so I guess you can just do it that way.

Comment: Looks like it's not in [netstandard1.6](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard1.6_ref.md)

Comment: which.NetFramework you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `Array.AsReadOnly` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.asreadonly?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002735#applies-to) indeed does not exist in .Net Core 1.x and .Net Standard 1.x.

It will be included in .Net Core 2.0 and .Net Standard 2.0.
In the meantime, you can use `new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(array)`, as has already been suggested.

Comment: I still cannot find AsReadOnly in .Net Core 2.1, I am missing something?